# How can i get weekly (from day to day) of one month in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data as below:

```
Docdate                Qty   Amount
-----------------------------------
2014/08/01(Friday)     5     100
2014/08/03(Sunday)     5     100
2014/08/04(Monday)     8     100
2014/08/10(Sunday)     8     100
2014/08/11(Monday)     8     100
2014/08/17(Sunday)     8     100
2014/08/18(Monday)     8     100
2014/08/24(Sunday)     8     100
2014/08/25(Monday)     8     100
2014/08/31(Sunday)     8     100
```

I want to general a stored procedure with below template:

```
Item QtyWeek1(1-3) QtyWeek2(4-10) QtyWeek3(11-17) QtyWeek4(18-24) QtyWeek5(25-31)
A    10             16            16              16              16
B    -              -             -                -              -
```

Is it possible to do that in stored procedure?

Is it possible to do that in Crystal Report? If yes, what stored procedure columns should be displayed?

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your post to show what you attempted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, if you column Docdate DATETIME type

```
SELECT item, SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(wk, Docdate) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS qtyWeek1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(wk, Docdate) BETWEEN 4 AND 10 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS qtyWeek2, 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(wk, Docdate) BETWEEN 11 AND 17 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS qtyWeek3,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(wk, Docdate) BETWEEN 18 AND 24 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS qtyWeek4,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(wk, Docdate) BETWEEN 25 AND 31 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) AS qtyWeek5

FROM YouTable 
GROUP BY item
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy at all. I suppose you have one more column name item and you would like to have always five weeks, and so I had to consider an extra column YYYYMM to contains the month of the weeks belong.

Then the query would be:

```
select ITEM, MONTH_YEAR, [1] WEEK1, [2] WEEK2, [3] WEEK3, [4] WEEK4, [5] WEEK5
from (
   select 
      ITEM, 
      YEAR(DATE1)*100+MONTH(DATE1) MONTH_YEAR,
      1 + WEEK - WEEK0 WEEK,
      sum(Qty) Qty
   from Table1 t1
   cross apply (SELECT cast(Replace(LEFT(DocDate,10),'/','-') as date)) N(DATE1)
   cross apply (SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATE1))) T(WEEK)
   cross apply (SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, DateAdd(day, -1, DateAdd(month, MONTH(DATE1) - 1, DateAdd(Year, YEAR(DATE1)-1900, 0))))) U(WEEK0)
   group by WEEK, YEAR(DATE1)*100+MONTH(DATE1), WEEK0, ITEM
) A
pivot (sum(QTY) FOR WEEK in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) B
```

Glossary:

- DATE1 represents the conversion of DocDate column in date type
- WEEK represents the number of the week
- WEEK0 represents the number of the first week of the month

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e56c54/1)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have crystal reports *DO NOT* do the crosstab in the database. Do it in crystal report.

If you look at anyones regular advice on this it is: **do the pivot in the reporting tool**

General solution is:

Add a single column to your existing recordset called, say `weeknumber`,

Map your existing `DocDate` to the week number (you'll need to explain the rules, i.e. when does a week start, what is week 1 etc., then I can suggest some code)

In crystal reports create a crosstab report which pivots on the new column `weeknumber`.

That way if you have 2 or 20 columns, crystal will take care of it, rather than hard coding in a database object.